# Mysql+PHP+Ajax как правильно?

Tags: php, mysql

Задам теоретический вопрос:
Необходимо разобраться с правильной работой базы данных mysql с PHP, основами владею - могу сохранять, выводить и прочее, но есть нюансы:

1. Есть связанные таблицы - какие способы существуют выбора данных из связанной таблицы? Т.Е. какой смысл связей между таблицами, как это используется в PHP?
2. Не могу понять как правильно должно работать следующее:
   Есть например Input в который должно попасть значение из базы, потом есть кнопка по нажатию на которую данные из input должны записаться в базу. Здесь есть два варианта: Первый делается запрос в базу - выясняется, что данных в базе еще нет которые должны попасть в input поэтому он остается пустым, затем его ручками меняют и при нажатии на кнопку сохранить должен отправиться запрос на добавление НОВОЙ записи (т.е. Insert into table123 ....). Второй когда данные в базе уже есть и они подгружаются в input, затем input опять меняют ручками и запрос уже должен быть не на добавление новой записи и на обновление старой (Т.е. Update ....). Как вообще правильно организовать такое когда на форме целая куча таких inputов?

Comment: Связи в БД к php не имеют никакого отношения. Они нужны для того, что бы ошибки в коде на php не привели БД в противоречивое состояние. Например когда в таблице свойств объекта есть данные для объекта ID=99, а в таблице объектов такого объекта просто не существует.

Comment: И вне зависимости от количества input'ов обычно вся страница целиком работает с 1-2 таблицами. А часто - с одной единственной записью основной таблицы и, возможно, с несколькими подчиненными ей. Так что на страницу или запись в html-таблице вы сразу при формировании html знаете взяли вы это запись из БД или она новая, фиксируете этот факт в каком-нибудь hidden поле и на основе него решаете insert или update применять

Comment: Слишком много нужно объяснять в этой теме для вашего уровня знаний. Попробуйте погуглить связку php и mysql. https://htmlweb.ru/php/mysql.php http://addphp.ru/materials/mysql/1_5.php http://intop24.ru/article_15_lesson_5.php

Answer (score 1):

Если запрос через jquery - то отправляйте просто форму в обработчик и там обновляйте или добавляйте. Рекомендую в форме скрытым полем выводить id записи, если она есть - тогда в обработчике что бы выяснить select или update достаточно проверить наличие id. Соответственно при наличие обновлять Update ... Where id=received_id